# Reduce score when clicking next to image but stop at 0

Tags: java

I am building a Java game and it's kind of working the way I want. The only thing is that when I click next to the object. The score reduces with 1. But it goes on and on.
I want this score to stop at `0` instead of going to `-1, -2, -3 etc.`

If I click the object I get `1` score, and when I click next to the object I will get `-1` score.

Question:
How do I stop reducing score after it's come to 0?

This is my score code:

```
    scoreLabel.setFont(new Font("Open Sans", Font.PLAIN, 30));
    scoreLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    scoreLabel.setBounds(20, 455, 200, 100);
    add(scoreLabel);

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            Point p = e.getPoint();
            int clickX = (int)p.getX();
            int clickY = (int)p.getY();

            if(clickX > x && clickX < x + 100 && clickY > y && clickY  < y + 100) {
                score++;
                scoreLabel.setText("SCORE: " + score);
            }else{
                score = score -1;
                scoreLabel.setText("SCORE: " + score);
            }

        }
    });
```

I hope it's clear.

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone, and each tag has a specific definition.  Tags aren't keywords.  Stuffing your tag list full of the same words that are in your question doesn't help categorize it.  Always make sure to read the helpful descriptions that appear when entering tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put an `if` there in your `else` block.

```
}else{
    if (score > 0){
        score = score -1;
        scoreLabel.setText("SCORE: " + score);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm so stupid. Lol, this is easy. I also know javascript and php very well, so this is the same stuff. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
 else if(score>0){
            score = score -1;
            scoreLabel.setText("SCORE: " + score);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks this helped. I can only accept 1 answer, so I will upvote yours.

Answer (score 1):

change the code to check score before decreasing :

```
if(clickX > x && clickX < x + 100 && clickY > y && clickY  < y + 100) {
  score++;
  scoreLabel.setText("SCORE: " + score);
} else if(score != 0) {
  score = score -1;
  scoreLabel.setText("SCORE: " + score);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped. I can only accept 1 answer, so I will upvote yours.

Answer (score 1):

Use Math.max(0, score -1)

```
        if(clickX > x && clickX < x + 100 && clickY > y && clickY  < y + 100) {
            score++;
            scoreLabel.setText("SCORE: " + score);
        }else{
            score = Math.max(0, score -1);
            scoreLabel.setText("SCORE: " + score);
        }
```

Comment: Is this a better option than just  if (score > 0){ ?

Comment: Just another option. To me it code looks cleaner with Math.max(..)